# What is the oxygen filter on Super Heavy, and how could it get blocked on IFT-3?

Tags: spacex-starship, failure

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship_integrated_flight_test_2

> On February 26, 2024, SpaceX stated that the most likely root cause was filter blockage where liquid oxygen is supplied to the engines, leading to a loss of inlet pressure in engine oxidizer turbopumps that eventually resulted in one engine failing, resulting in loss of the vehicle.

What is this filter for? Why would they need a filter? What could clog it?

Comment: I've been wondering if the "blockage" they keep talking about is actually an air bubble.

Comment: I found a [Smithsonian Magazine article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/is-spacex-changing-the-rocket-equation-132285884/) that briefly mentions feeding a stainless steel nut into the fuel/oxidizer lines for a Merlin engine as part of engine qualification. If I can find a more complete source more related to SuperHeavy I'll try to write a decent answer

Comment: Also, the [Virgin Orbit failure](https://www.space.com/virgin-orbit-united-kingdom-flight-failure-cause) from January of last year was due to a dislodged fuel filter

Answer (score 4):

No specific knowledge of Starship, but the shuttle Orbiters had filters in their main propulsion feedlines; the same reasons should apply to Starship.

Namely, keeping loose hardware that was mistakenly left lying around in the propulsion system out of the turbopumps!

What could clog it? Loose hardware / packing material / cleaning rags that was (were) mistakenly left lying around in the propulsion system!

This is a crop of the [Space Shuttle Systems Handbook Drawing 10.8 LO2 System](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC-11174%20-%20Space_Shuttle_Systems_Handbook_Vol2.pdf). I have highlighted the oxygen prevalve, the engine O2 inlet, and the 1000 micron filter.

[image]

These pages are from the [MPS Components Manual](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/Main%20Propulsion%20System%20Components%20Manual.pdf).

[image]

[image]

As an aside, when I worked in the shuttle Systems Integration Office, there were always arguments about whether or not to breach the systems to retrieve material seen on the filters in boroscope inspections. Would it be riskier to go after it, or not? The business of Systems Integration.

Comment: Confirming that is a micron filter in a drawing otherwise using US units? The choice of 1000 micron rather than 1mm is interesting but I guess in keeping with general filter terminology so may just be how the OEM described/defined it.

Comment: @GremlinWranger added some info stating explicitly that it's 1000 microns, and a locater diagram.

Comment: What kind of / how much "material" was seen on the filters?

Comment: @ikrase It varied. I remember a "metallic particle" and a scrap of tape or some such material (two different incidents).